# How to count specific sub documents on other sub documents in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a schema like this struct:

```json
{
    "user" : "admin",
    "exercises" : [
        {
            "name" : "exercise 1",
            "documents" : [
                {
                    "idDoc" : "1",
                    "name" : "doc1"
                },
                {
                    "idDoc" : "2",
                    "name" : "doc1"
                },
                {
                    "idDoc" : "3",
                    "name" : "doc2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I count all documents that have name = `doc1`?

The output is:

```json
{
    "_id" : "objectId", --userId
    "count" : 2
}
```

I know this below code can count all document but I don't have any idea to count them with conditions.

```js
Schema.aggregate()
            .match({ user: username })
            .project({ size: {
                $reduce : {
                    "input" : "$exercises",
                    "initialValue" : 0,
                    "in" : {"$add":["$$value",{"$size":"$$this.documents"}]}
                }
            }});
```

Please help! Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going the right way by using [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/), just need some changes in data processing. You can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) with [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to create an array that has all documents with name `doc1` then use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to count items in that array. Example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { user: "admin" } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      count: {
        $size: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$exercises",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$this.documents",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$item.name", "doc1"] }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GFAUOED5ewc)